# Javascript pattern not matching

Tags: javascript

I am trying to match pattern which contains pipe(|) operator.

Have used below code to match patteren

```
var format = /[ \\|]/; // This is the pattern for matching pipe pattern

if ("Near raghavendra temple ring roads".match(format)) {
    alert("Invalid character");
}
```

`"Near raghavendra temple ring roads"` this string does not contains | operator but still above condition getting true.

Not able to to understand what is the mistake in above pattern.

Comment: https://regexr.com/3i02n

Comment: In case you haven't used it before, https://regex101.com/ is great for explaining the semantics of a regex pattern.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var format = /[\\|]/; // This is the pattern for matching pipe pattern

if ("Near raghavendra temple ring roads".match(format))
  console.log("Invalid character");

else
  console.log('All valid');
```

You are matching on the space character.  Remove the space from the regex pattern (inside the square) brackets

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have a space in there:

```
/[ \\|]/
```

actually means "match any one space, `\` or `|`".

If all you want to do is match a pipe, then use this:

```js
const format = /[\|]/; // This is the pattern for matching pipe pattern

if ("Near raghavendra temple ring roads".match(format)) {
  console.log("Invalid character");
} else {
  console.log("Okay");
}
```

You probably have the double-`\` because that's how it needs to appear in strings. However, in regex, if you do two, it makes it a `\` literal. If you just want to escape the pipe, just use one.

In fact, in a set like that, you don't even need to escape it:

```js
const format = /[|]/; // This is the pattern for matching pipe pattern

if ("Near raghavendra temple ring roads".match(format)) {
  console.log("Invalid character");
} else {
  console.log("Okay");
}

if ("Bad | character".match(format)) {
  console.log('Bad character');
}
```

Personally, I like to keep the slash though just for clarity.